# JavaScript não reconhece número 10

Tags: javascript

Estou com um probleminha que não sei como resolver.

Nesse código abaixo  ele faz o seguinte.... de acordo com um drop down com values de 0 a 10
sendo que a opção selecionada for menor que 8 ele mostrar uma div oculta, se form maior não faz nada.

Bem ele funciona muito bem mais ate o número 9  se escolher no dropdown o número 10 ele mostra a div oculta

```
   <select name="pes11" id="privileges1" class=""        
   onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>  --> ok 
   <option value="2">2</option>  --> ok
   <option value="3">3</option>  --> ok
   <option value="4">4</option>  --> ok
   <option value="5">5</option>  --> ok
   <option value="6">6</option>  --> ok
   <option value="7">7</option>  --> ok
   <option value="8">8</option>  --> ok
   <option value="9">9</option>  --> ok
   <option value="10">10</option> --> ERRO acho que reconhece o 10 como 1
   </select>
   <script>
   var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges1');
   var select = this.value;Privileges.change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() < '8') {
   $('.txt').show();
   }
   else $('.txt').hide();
   });
   </script>

   <div class="txt" style=" display: none;">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar um parseInt() no seu $(this).val() e se quiser remover as aspas simples de seu valor também funcionara..

```
var Privileges = jQuery('#privileges1');
var select = this.value;

Privileges.change(function () {
   if (parseInt($(this).val()) < 8) {
        $('.txt').show();
   } else { 
       $('.txt').hide();
   }
});
```